# Asynchronous while loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, background-process

I try my windows phone app running in the background. Using a While loop that starts at leaving the app, everything works fine. But when I go into the app again, the app hangs in the infinite loop and does not load. That's why I have written a condition in the while loop, but as long as the while loop is running, no other code is considered. Is there an asynchronous while loop or something to solve the problem.

Here is my code from App.xaml.cs:

```
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    WhileLoop();
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Continue = false;
}

static bool Continue = false;

void WhileLoop()
{
   Continue = true;
   while(Continue == true)
   {
         //do something in background
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about WP, but I'm guessing the "on close" hook (i.e., `Application_Closing`) shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds to return...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard for me to guess what you mean by running in Background. If you mean running under lock screen, then it's possible by Disabling `IdleDetection`, but that's not probably what you want to achieve as I see Closing Event and so on.

In other case when programming Windows Phone, you must know few things:

- as @dcastro said in comment you have limited time when App is Closing or Dectivated,
- when App is Closing, then no method, thread or anything will "survive" (or shouldn't)
- when App is Deactivated - all Threads, BackroundWorkers (allmost everything connected with your App) is stopped, as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) says:
  `When the user navigates forward, away from an app, after the Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put the app into a dormant state. In this state, all of the application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but the application remains intact in memory.`
- the other problem is when your App is Tombstoned, then most of its resources is released,
- you may perform some actions in the background by using [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- or you may try to save the state of your App in IsolatedStorage or PhoneApplicationService State, (you can read more about it [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) ) - save upon Deactivation, then restore upon Activation
  Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that the background worker does not work in background. With background, I mean that after clicking on the windows button the app should still continue to run.

Comment: @user2799780 Then I've understood you correct - when you press Start Button, your App is Deactivated (you can read above what happens). Your App won't run when you hit Start Button (if you need some background action you can set Background Agent). I think you should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @user2799780 You're trying to do something that the OS doesn't want you to do. There is probably a better solution for whatever you want to do if you gave more information on WHY you're trying to run in the background. As Romasz has said, you have the option to use a BackgroundAgent for certain background tasks.

Comment: I want that a timer send's a alarm e.x. in 40 seconds when the App is closed. I tried it with the reminder function but the alarm can only ring after on minute

Comment: @user2799780 I don't know what you try to do, but with such a small interval it can be hard to do. Background Agents AFAIK - periodic agents min. interval is 10 minutes, and ResourceIntensive has many constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move your loop onto a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) because at the minute once the `while` loop starts  it will hog the CPU in the UI thread which means no other messages will get processed i.e. your `Application_Activated` event.

The problem is you are trying to break out of an infinite loop which is running in the *same thread*. If your `while` loop was on a different thread (i.e. not hogging the UI thread) then your code should work. However, I think there are better ways of doing this without using

1. An infinite loop
2. A `static` field

For example, a more robust approach would be to keep a reference to a `BackgroundWorker` on `Application_Closing` and then on `Application_Activated` you could call [CancelAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on it, this would allow you to use the `CancellationPending` property inside your BW for a safer shutdown of the background process.

Answer (score -2):

```
    using System.Threading;

    ManualResetEventSlim waitEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false); // start in the unsignaled state

    async void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        await MyLoop();    // execute asynchronously
        waitEvent.Wait();  // wait for a signal to continue
    }

    void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        waitEvent.Reset(); // set unsignaled
    }

    Task MyLoop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(condition)
                break;
        }

        waitEvent.Set(); // signal the app to continue
    }
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? `Wait` is just going to block as if `MyLoop` were synchronous.